# Image broken when linking with img src url

Tags: html

If you check the link, there is a valid image there.
With the following code, which should be correct, the image displays as broken.

```
<img src="https://media.go2speed.org/brand/files/ogmobi/22052/thumbnails_100/rogiudid-100.png">
```

Comment: What is the infrastructure of your application? Application server?

Comment: Press Shift + Ctrl + R on your system while the browser is open to see if it solve your problem.

Comment: Which device and browser you're running the test on?

Comment: If just a reload not work, it's a big chance of your image has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin. Your browser console give some message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the server has [disabled image hot linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking), basically, the go2speed.org is not allowing your domain (say, www.my-domain.com) to show that image and instead cherry-picks which domains can show their images.

This is a technique done frequently to avoid bandwidth pressure or costs on a server.

**EDIT:** Nevermind, I just [made a jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/YuanHaoChiang/mze31Lsb/3/) and the image works on Chrome, but not on Firefox:

```
<img src="https://media.go2speed.org/brand/files/ogmobi/22052/thumbnails_100/rogiudid-100.png">
```

```html
Works:

<img src="https://theme.zdassets.com/theme_assets/808026/f5a632c04387e943991e9c334c7b3b1e7254b8ea.png" />

Works on Chrome but not Firefox?

<img src="https://media.go2speed.org/brand/files/ogmobi/22052/thumbnails_100/rogiudid-100.png">
```

A quick look on the network shows that Chrome/FF don't identify it as an image right away, but instead as a document. This could mess up the img src on Firefox for some reason (although opening in a new tab works).